# How to insert an image on line to all \section and \subsection?

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I have to insert an image a begin of every `\section` and `\subsection` using those LaTeX commands.

I have tried this:

```
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\mbox{\includegraphics{FigureFISSE/IconaT1.eps}\quad\mbox{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{0.5em}}}
```

but typsetting the following error appears:

> ```
> 32: Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
> <inserted text> 
>                 \par 
> <to be read again> 
>                    }
> \@sect ...tected@edef \@svsec {\@seccntformat {#1}
>                                                   \relax }\fi \@tempskipa #5...
> l.32 ...ùòlkz xùl<k xùòlk<zxùlòk <ùòzlxk <ùòlxzk }
> ```

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\mbox{\includegraphics{FigureFISSE/IconaT1.eps}\quad\mbox{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{0.5em}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Prova titolo}



Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo 
\section{Titolo sezione lòk xùl<kùxzlk òs àòsk fòskf àksò fdjks<ùòlxk ù<òlxk <ùòlkz xùl<k xùòlk<zxùlòk <ùòzlxk <ùòlxzk }
Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo 

\subsection{Titolo 2}
Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo 
Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Make a complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: \documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\mbox{\includegraphics{FigureFISSE/IconaT1.eps}\quad\mbox{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{0.5em}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Prova titolo}



Testo testo TTesto testo Testo testo 
\section{Titolo sezione lòk xùl<kùxzlk òs àòsk fòskf àksò fdjks<ùòlxk ù<òlxk <ùòlkz xùl<k xùòlk<zxùlòk <ùòzlxk <ùòlxzk }
Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo 

\subsection{Titolo 2}
Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo 

\end{document}

Comment: Don't add examples as comments. Edit your question. And use a graphic that is not local, e.g. one from the mwe package.

Comment: I have added an image of one page showing what I need. Sorry, but I don't know how to attach the LaTex document

Comment: Your document doesn't load the graphicx package. Beside this: try `\protect\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to LaTeX.sx.

I think that you need the package named `titlesec`, it lets you customize any heading, in this example I changed a section style.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,graphicx}

\titleformat{\section}
{\LARGE\bfseries}
{\includegraphics{FigureFISSE/IconaT1.eps}\quad \thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\Large\bfseries}
{\includegraphics{FigureFISSE/IconaT1.eps}\quad \thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Some nice text.

\end{document}
```

You can find this in the manual page of the titlesec package, section 9.1 and 9.2. Just google it and you will find, or search on CTAN. I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer, but perhaps you should recast it in a form that is more readily compileable and presents all the changes, such as `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,graphicx}
\titleformat{\section}
{\LARGE\bfseries}
{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-A}\quad \thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\Large\bfseries}
{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\quad \thesubsection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Some nice text.

\subsection{Introduction}
Some nice text.
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

You're just forgetting `\protect`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \protect\includegraphics[height=1.5ex]{example-image}\quad
  \csname the#1\endcsname\enspace
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Prova titolo}

Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo

\section{Titolo sezione abbastanza lungo per andare a capo, potrebbe bastare}

Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo

\subsection{Titolo 2}
Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo
Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo Testo testo

\end{document}
```

[image]